# Rename columns in a large list with different data frame lengths

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

I have used `lapply` to create a large list containing +14000 individual data frames with various lengths, see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/427507/155292) question for more background.

I now have a large list with many data frames that have different numbers of columns, ranging from 84 to 315. I would like to rename every data frame columns with two consistent names and a sequence from d0 to dxx, depending on the number of columns

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5 ... colxx
  ID    doy     d0     d1     d2       dxx
```

This means the first data frame will have a sequence of d0 to d312, while the last data frame will have a sequence of `d0 to d81`.

I tried the following:

```
df = lapply(df_sub, function(x) {names(x)[1:314] <- c("ID", "doy","d0","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9","d10","d11","d12","d13","d14","d15","d16","d17","d18","d19","d20","d21","d22","d23","d24","d25","d26","d27","d28","d29","d30",                             "d31","d32","d33","d34","d35","d36","d37","d38","d39","d40","d41","d42","d43","d44","d45","d46","d47","d48","d49","d50",d51","d52","d53","d54","d55","d56","d57","d58","d59","d60",d61","d62","d63","d64","d65","d66","d67","d68","d69","d70","d71","d72","d73","d74","d75","d76","d77","d78","d79","d80","d81","d82","d83","d84","d85","d86","d87","d88","d89","d90","d91","d92","d93","d94","d95","d96","d97","d98","d99","d100",d101","d102","d103","d104","d105","d106","d107","d108","d109","d110","d111","d112","d113","d114","d115","d116","d117","d118","d119","d120","d121","d122","d123","d124","d125","d126","d127","d128","d129","d130","d131","d132","d133","d134","d135","d136","d137","d138","d139","d140","d141","d142","d143","d144","d145","d146","d147","d148","d149","d150","d151","d152","d153","d154","d155","d156","d157","d158","d159","d160","d161","d162","d163","d164","d165","d166","d167","d168","d169","d170","d171","d172","d173","d174","d175","d176","d177","d178","d179","d180","d181","d182","d183","d184","d185","d186","d187","d188","d189","d190","d191","d192","d193","d194","d195","d196","d197","d198","d199","d200","d201","d202","d203","d204","d205","d206","d207","d208","d209","d210","d211","d212","d213","d214","d215","d216","d217","d218","d219","d220","d221","d222","d223","d224","d225","d226","d227","d228","d229","d230","d231","d232","d233","d234","d235","d236","d237","d238","d239","d240","d241","d242","d243","d244","d245","d246","d247","d248","d249","d250","d251","d252","d253","d254","d255","d256","d257","d258","d259","d260","d261","d262","d263","d264","d265","d266","d267","d268","d269","d270","d271","d272","d273","d274","d275","d276","d277","d278","d279","d280","d281","d282","d283","d284","d285","d286","d287","d288","d289","d290","d291","d292","d293","d294","d295","d296","d297","d298","d299","d300","d301","d302","d303","d304","d305","d306","d307","d308","d309","d310","d311","d312"); x})

Error in names(x) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  'names' attribute [315] must be the same length as the vector [314]
```

How can this be done otherwise in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only works if there are three or more columns, but I guess that can be assumed here.

```r
# Sample Data
df <- lapply(list(mtcars,iris,CO2), head)

lapply(df, function(d) {setNames(d, c("ID", "doy", paste0("d", 0:(length(d) - 3))))})
#> [[1]]
#>                     ID doy  d0  d1   d2    d3    d4 d5 d6 d7 d8
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1  4  4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1  4  4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1  4  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0  3  1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0  3  2
#> Valiant           18.1   6 225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0  3  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    ID doy  d0  d1     d2
#> 1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
#> 2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
#> 3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
#> 4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
#> 5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
#> 6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    ID    doy         d0  d1   d2
#> 1 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  95 16.0
#> 2 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 175 30.4
#> 3 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 250 34.8
#> 4 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 350 37.2
#> 5 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 500 35.3
#> 6 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 675 39.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(magrittr)

# example data
dfs <- list(
  data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
  data.frame(x = 1, y = 2),
  data.frame(z = 0)
)

dfs %>%
  lapply(function(.x) {
    colnames(.x) <-
      .x %>%
      colnames() %>%
      length() %>%
      seq() %>%
      `-`(1) %>%
      paste0("d", .)
    .x
  })
#> [[1]]
#>   d0 d1 d2
#> 1  1  2  3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   d0 d1
#> 1  1  2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   d0
#> 1  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Nice! An alternative to `\`-\`()` could be `subtract()` since `magrittr` is already loaded. It might make for slightly more readable code.

Comment: In newer versions of R > 4.1 one can replace `%>%` with the native pipe `|>` making `magrittr` unnecessary.

Comment: True. Mostly I've got dplyr or similar packages already loaded, so I would just use `%>%` and do the same as you with `\`-\`()`, but I thought it worth mentioning just since `magrittr` provides these aliases just for pleasant piping. See `?magrittr::extract` for similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification to your existing code is to check how many columns the dataframe has, before creating the new names:

```
df <- list()
for(i in 1:3) df[[i]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 5, i+3))

f <- function(x){
  #Names first column "ID", second "Day", and subsequent columns d0, d1...
  names(x) <- c("ID","Day", paste0("d", seq(from=0, length.out=length(names(x))-2)))  
  x
}

lapply(df, f)
# [[1]]
#   ID Day d0 d1
# 1 NA  NA NA NA
# 2 NA  NA NA NA
# 3 NA  NA NA NA
# 4 NA  NA NA NA
# 5 NA  NA NA NA
# 
# [[2]]
#   ID Day d0 d1 d2
# 1 NA  NA NA NA NA
# 2 NA  NA NA NA NA
# 3 NA  NA NA NA NA
# 4 NA  NA NA NA NA
# 5 NA  NA NA NA NA
# 
# [[3]]
#   ID Day d0 d1 d2 d3
# 1 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
# 2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
# 3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
# 4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
# 5 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
```